# OpenCV Projection Matrix Choice

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, computer-vision, vision

I am currently facing a problem, to depict you what my programm does and should do, here is the copy/paste of the beginning of a previous post I've made.

This program lies on the classic "structure from motion" method.

The basic idea is to take a pair of images, detect their keypoints and compute the descriptors of those keypoints. Then, the keypoints matching is done, with a certain number of tests to insure the result is good. That part works perfectly.

Once this is done, the following computations are performed : fundamental matrix, essential matrix, SVD decomposition of the essential matrix, camera projection matrices computation and finally, triangulation.

The result for a pair of images is a set of 3D coordinates, giving us points to be drawn in a 3D viewer. This works perfectly, for a pair.

However, I have to perform a step manually, and this is not acceptable if I want my program to efficiently work with more than two images.

Indeed, I compute my projection matrices according the classic method, as follows, at paragraph "Determining R and t from E" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix

I have then 4 possible solutions for my projection matrix.

I think I have understood the geometrical point of view of the problem, portrayded in this Hartley and Zisserman paper extract (chapters 9.6.3 and 9.7.1) : http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZepipolar.pdf

Nonetheless, my question is : **Given the four possible projection matrices computed and the 3D points computed by the OpenCV function triangulatePoints() (for each projection matrix), how can I elect the "true" projection matrix, automatically ?** (without having to draw 4 times my points in my 3D viewer, in order to see if they are consistent)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The solution is given in the article you linked... "Thus, testing
with a single point to determine if it is in front of both cameras is sufficient to decide between the four different solutions for the camera matrix P'". No need to draw anything in a viewer. Just do some computations with the coordinates (probably a scalar product somewhere)

Comment: Yes, I have read this indeed, and I understand the geometric configurations. What I have trouble with is to transpose this test in my program :, having only the relative positions of the cameras is not an issue ? Then I would have to assume that my first camera is at the origin ?

Comment: Of course. How would you define an absolute position ? In the Middle Ages, people believed that Earth was at the center of the universe, thus giving an absolute position to everything. Now we know it's not true so any position you can define will be a relative one.

Comment: Yes. But in this case would the use of this function http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#decomposeprojectionmatrix be of any help ? In order to compute the Euler angles and to have the exact relative position of camera 2 ? So I would have camera 1 = origin, camera 2 relative position and orientation, and my points coordinates. I would be able to determine wether or not a point is "good" with that nope ?